# extracting part of a data frame with a wild card

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, wildcard

Say you want to build a data frame that is a fraction on another, like a SQL query:

`SELECT * from df WHERE columns_name is in ("a", "b", "c")`.

I assumed dplyr includes this function but I don't see a wildcard option in it.
 
What I need is to filter on rows with very long string values, that could easily be specified as containing `%something_a%`, `%something_b%`, or `%something_c%`. I bet there is a simple way of doing it - anyone knows what it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use grepl, like in the following example:

```
df <- data.frame(fruits = c("apple", "banana", "cherry"))
df %>% 
     filter(grepl("app", fruits))
```

grepl uses regular expressions, and you can use them to check for patterns in your strings.

Comment: in order to compose a regex I recommend this: https://regexr.com/